# C build pipes for command 'ls -lR [-ddir] | sort | grep string [ >outfile]'

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

For my homework I have to create a program in C that is equivalent to the shell command 'ls -lR [dir] | sort | grep string [ >outfile]' with the syntax 'lsgrep [-ddir] string [-foutfile]'.

For some reason the second pipe (which should be connected to the grep-child-process) doesn't seem to work properly.

When I remove the third child process (grep) the program prints the sorted 'ls -lR' contents and terminates. Therefore I think the problem is related to the second pipe (sortgrep).

```
    ...
    // ls -lR [dir] | sort | grep string [ >outfile]
    // -------------^------^------------------------
    int lssort[2];
    int sortgrep[2];

    pipe(lssort);
    pipe(sortgrep);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
      close(STDOUT_FILENO);
      dup(lssort[1]);
      close(lssort[0]);
      char * argv[] =
      { "ls", "-lR", parameters.dirIsSet ? dir : (char *) NULL, (char *) NULL };
      execvp("ls", argv);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
      close(STDIN_FILENO);
      dup(lssort[0]);
      close(lssort[1]);

      close(STDOUT_FILENO);
      dup(sortgrep[1]);
      close(sortgrep[0]);

      char * argv[] = { "sort", (char *) NULL };
      execvp("sort", argv);
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
      close(STDIN_FILENO);
      dup(sortgrep[0]);
      close(sortgrep[1]);

      if (parameters.outfileIsSet)
      {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        int fd = open(outfile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
        if (fd == -1) perror("Error: Could not open file");
        dup(fd);
        close(fd);
      }

      char * argv[] = { "grep", string, (char *) NULL };
      execvp("grep", argv);
    }

    close(lssort[0]);
    close(lssort[1]);

    close(sortgrep[0]);
    close(sortgrep[1]);

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);

    wait(0);
    wait(0);

    return 0;
    ...
```

My expected output when running the program would be

1. 'ls -lR [-ddir]' lists the contents of the (optionally given/current working) directory and pipes them through the pipe 'lssort' to the next child process (sort)
2. 'sort' sorts the contents received from the pipe 'lssort' and pipes the results through 'sortgrep' to the next child process (grep)
3. 'grep string [-foutfile]' selects lines which match the given pattern (string) and prints them to stdout or if defined to a log file (outfile)

In fact the program just keeps on running/waiting for input. When I run 'top' in another terminal I can see that sort and grep are sleeping.

Comment: Your use of `dup` is a bit fragile. I suggest you either use `dup2` or at least check the returned fd is what you expected. You can find out exactly what is happening by running it under `strace -ff -o strace` (to follow forks and separate the trace for each child process)

Comment: for replacing e. g.

`close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup(lssort[1]);
close(lssort[0]);`

with dup2 it would be like this ?

`close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(lssort[1], STDOUT_FILENO);`

Comment: Yep. I know `dup` uses the lowest available fd, but it relies on implicit knowledge, rather than being explicit in the code. It's also fragile in the face of refactoring or reordering code.

Comment: Ok i have replaced the dup calls by dup2 calls but I doesn't seem to change the behaviour when I run the program.

How do i have to use `strace -ff -o strace`?

Comment: stick that lot at the start of the command line and `/path/to/your/executable` at the end. It'll give you a trace of every system call made by every child process in separate files.

Comment: Is your assignment to write a C program that **behaves** like the shell command line? Or to write a C program that **invokes** the commands in a sub shell?

Comment: I have to write a C program that **behaves** like the shell command line. To do that I have to use fork, pipe & exec.